# A working sample of code action and quick fix in the playground

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm looking for a sample of code action with quick fix that works in the playground. I tried this code in the [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html), but it did not work.

```js
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'mySpecialLanguage' });

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "const foo = 1;",
    language: "mySpecialLanguage",
    lightbulb: { enabled: false },
});

monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider('mySpecialLanguage', {
    provideHover: function (model, position) {
        return {
            range: new monaco.Range(1,1,1,5),
            contents: [
                { value: "Let's correct it" }
            ]
        };
    }
});

monaco.languages.registerCodeActionProvider('javascript', {
    provideCodeActions(model, range, context, token) {
        return Promise.resolve({
            actions: [{
                title: "Testing",
                diagnostics: [{
                    code: "0",
                    endColumn: 5,
                    endLineNumber: 1,
                    message: "message",
                    severity: 8,
                    startColumn: 1,
                    startLineNumber: 1,
                }],
                edit: {
                    edits: [{
                        edit: { 
                            range: new monaco.Range(1, 1, 1, 5), 
                            text: `text` },
                        resource: model.uri,
                    }],
                },
                kind: "quickfix",
                title: "title"
            }],
            dispose: () => { },
        })
    }
});
```

What I expect is, we could hover on `const foo = 1`, then we see `Let's correct it`, under which we could see `Quick Fix`, on which we could click to fix.

[image]

Does anyone know why the code does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer - for Monaco 0.34.0 and above**

Since Monaco 0.34.0, the original solution below needs a slight tweak to work. The `edit` object that contains the `range` and `text` properties needs to be renamed as `textEdit` like this:

```
edit: {
    edits: [
        {
            resource: model.uri,
            textEdit: {
                range: error,
                text: "replacement text" // text to replace with
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

**Original Answer - for Monaco 0.33.X and below**

I'm not sure why the code you posted doesn't work, but if you copy and paste the below code into the [Monaco Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html), it will display a quickfix named `My quickfix` and replace the text highlighted as an error with the words `replacement text`:

```js
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'myLanguage' });

monaco.editor.onDidCreateModel(function(model) {
    function validate() {
      var textToValidate = model.getValue();
      
      var markers = [{
        severity: monaco.MarkerSeverity.Error,
        startLineNumber: 1,
        startColumn: 3,
        endLineNumber: 1,
        endColumn: 5,
        message: 'Lets correct it'
      }];
      monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(model, 'myLanguage', markers);
    }

    var handle = null;
    model.onDidChangeContent(() => {
      // debounce
      clearTimeout(handle);
      handle = setTimeout(() => validate(), 500);
    });
    validate();
});

monaco.languages.registerCodeActionProvider("myLanguage", {
    provideCodeActions: (model, range, context, token) => {
        const actions = context.markers.map(error => {
            return {
                title: `My quickfix`, // Name of quickfix
                diagnostics: [error],
                kind: "quickfix",
                edit: {
                    edits: [
                        {
                            resource: model.uri,
                            edit: {
                                range: error,
                                text: "replacement text" // text to replace with
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                isPreferred: true
            };
        });
        return {
            actions: actions,
            dispose: () => {}
        }
    }
});

var ed = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "cont foo = 1;",
    language: "myLanguage",
    lightbulb: { enabled: false },
});
```

The `validate()` function in `monaco.editor.onDidCreateModel` adds a dummy error marker into the model which displays an error on line 1, column 3-5 . In a real world example, you'd probably want to validate `model.getValue()` in the `validate()` function and set the model markers based on the result of that validation.

The code within `monaco.editor.registerCodeActionProvider` defines the list of quick fixes you want to be displayed. In this example it is a hardcoded list with a single quickfix, but in real life, you would probably want to change the callback inside `context.markers.map` to some logic that checked the `error.message` property, and returned the correct suggestion for the message.

When you hover over the error on line 1, you will see `Lets correct it` and the `Quick Fix...` link. Clicking the `Quick Fix` link should display a single suggestion `My quickfix`. When you click on this, it will replace the text underlined by the error with the text defined in the quickfix (`replacement text`).

Comment: not op, tried this but it cause error Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported edit and the editor says something like "...is not assignable to type 'CodeActionList'.
      Types of property 'actions' are incompatible."

Comment: Looks like something changed in Monaco 0.34.0 and the code in the answer stopped working then. I'll have a look and try and update it for Monaco 0.34.0 and above

Comment: @Taunterexd I've updated the answer for newer versions of Monaco

Comment: thank you!! can i ask you how you managed to find this change? did you read all the update notes or you inspected something of the library?

Comment: @Taunterexd I looked at the error that was being thrown when using the later version of Monaco, mapped that back to my answer and managed to figure it out from that

Answer (score 0):

As of monaco version 0.44 you also need a additional versionId. The `edit` object that contains the `range` and `text` properties needs to be like this:

```
edit: {
    edits: [
        {
            resource: model.uri,
            textEdit: {
                range: error,
                text: "replacement text" // text to replace with
            },
            versionId: 1
        }
    ]
}
```