# Call quickFix by keyboard shortcuts

Tags: monaco-editor

I have an editor built by Monaco Editor. For certain texts, it returns certain code actions and quick fix.

[image]

However, the shortcut `Command + .` does not work in Mac and Chrome; `Ctrl + .` does not work in Windows and Chrome either (I use French keyboard). ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71742764/702977) is a working sample of quickFix provided by someone else, where shortcuts don't work either.)

Does anyone know what may be the reason?

I then tried to overwrite the shortcuts. I have the following code in `index.tsx`:

```
  handleEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    // I tried to follow `updateKeyBinding` of https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/102#issuecomment-822981429
    const id = "editor.action.quickFix"
    const newKeyBinding = monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.KeyP
    const { handler, when } = CommandsRegistry.getCommand(id) ?? {}
    editor._standaloneKeybindingService.addDynamicKeybinding(id, newKeyBinding, handler)

    //@ts-ignore
    editor._standaloneKeybindingService.addDynamicKeybinding('write-command' ,  monaco.KeyMod.Alt | monaco.KeyMod.Shift  | monaco.KeyCode.KeyS  , this.writeShortcutKey.bind(this)); 
  }
```

`writeShortcutKey` can be called by Alt+Shift+S, whereas quickFix cannot be called by Command+P

Does anyone know what's the correct way to assign a shortcut to `editor.action.quickFix`?

(* Link on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3055 *)

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcuts worked ok for me using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71742764/702977) in the [Monaco Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html). One thing to note is that when you load the Monaco playground, paste the code snippet and press `> Run`, the editor on the right hand side does not have focus (although hovering over the error underline in the editor will bring up the marker). For the keyboard shortcuts to work, you will need to place the cursor so the editor has focus and the cursor is  flashing.

If you click where the underlined text is (line 1, column 3) then press the keyboard shortcut, it will bring up the list of quick fixes (a single suggestion named `My quickfix` in this example).

If your cursor is not positioned on a bit of text in error (e.g. the cursor is at the end of line 1), pressing the shortcut will result in the message `No code actions available` being displayed.

If you do want to rebind any existing shortcuts, you can use the following code in the [Monaco Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) to unbind an existing keyboard shortcut and bind a new one:

```
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'myLanguage' });

monaco.editor.onDidCreateModel(function(model) {
    function validate() {
      var textToValidate = model.getValue();
      
      var markers = [{
        severity: monaco.MarkerSeverity.Error,
        startLineNumber: 1,
        startColumn: 3,
        endLineNumber: 1,
        endColumn: 5,
        message: 'Lets correct it'
      }];
      monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(model, 'myLanguage', markers);
    }

    var handle = null;
    model.onDidChangeContent(() => {
      // debounce
      clearTimeout(handle);
      handle = setTimeout(() => validate(), 500);
    });
    validate();
});

monaco.languages.registerCodeActionProvider("myLanguage", {
    provideCodeActions: (model, range, context, token) => {
        const actions = context.markers.map(error => {
            return {
                title: `My quickfix`, // Name of quickfix
                diagnostics: [error],
                kind: "quickfix",
                edit: {
                    edits: [
                        {
                            resource: model.uri,
                            edit: {
                                range: error,
                                text: "replacement text" // text to replace with
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                isPreferred: true
            };
        });
        return {
            actions: actions,
            dispose: () => {}
        }
    }
});

var ed = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "cont foo = 1;",
    language: "myLanguage",
    lightbulb: { enabled: false },
});

/**
 * Code to rebind the keyboard shortcut to quickFix
 */
// Get access to CommandsRegistry
const CommandsRegistry = require('vs/platform/commands/common/commands').CommandsRegistry;

// Get the handler and when properties for editor.action.quickFix
const { handler, when } = CommandsRegistry.getCommand("editor.action.quickFix") ?? {};

// Unbind the current keyboard shortcut
ed._standaloneKeybindingService.addDynamicKeybinding("-editor.action.quickFix", undefined, () => {});

// Add the new keyboard shortcut (bound to CtrlCmd+P)
const newKeyBinding = monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.KeyP;
ed._standaloneKeybindingService.addDynamicKeybinding("editor.action.quickFix", newKeyBinding, handler, when);
```

This line of code will unbind the current shortcut:

```
ed._standaloneKeybindingService.addDynamicKeybinding("-editor.action.quickFix", undefined, () => {});
```

And these lines binds the new one to `Ctrl+P`:

```
const newKeyBinding = monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.KeyP;
ed._standaloneKeybindingService.addDynamicKeybinding("editor.action.quickFix", newKeyBinding, handler, when);
```

As mentioned on [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/102#issuecomment-701938863) in the Github link you posted in your question,  this solution uses unofficial APIs (as there doesn't yet seem to be a public API for this).

Comment: Thank you. The keyboard shortcut does not work in [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71742764/702977) for me (Mac+Chrome+French keyboard), it might be because I'm using a French keyboard. But `Command+P` does work for the code you posted here. Do you know how to bind `Command+.` by using `const newKeyBinding = monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode...`? I'm thinking of unbinding the current shortcut for quickFix and rebinding it. I did not find the [keycode](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/enums/monaco.KeyCode.html) for `.`.

Comment: You could try rebinding it using `const newKeyBinding = monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Period;`

Comment: `const newKeyBinding = monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Period;` does show `⌘.`, but pressing the shortcut does not have effect.

Comment: I've tried the code snippet  in Chrome on both Mac and Linux and it works ok (English UK keyboard). If you add this `ed.onKeyDown(function(e) { console.log("keyDown", e.code); });` and type a `.` at the end of line 1 i the Monaco editor, does it log out `"KeyDown Period"`? Just wondering if there is a difference with keys on a French keyboard

Comment: Typing `.` prints `keyDown Comma`; pressing `⌘.` prints `keyDown MetaLeft`, `keyDown ShiftRight` and `keyDown Comma`. I tried to write `const newKeyBinding = monaco.KeyMod.Meta | monaco.KeyMod.Shift | monaco.KeyCode.Comma`, it showed `⇧,` near `Quick Fix`, but pressing `⌘.` does not have effect.

Comment: Does `const newKeyBinding = monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Comma;` work?