# Cleanup Marker in Monaco Editor once a quickFix(CodeAction) is clicked

Tags: monaco-editor

I am creating Code Actions (Quick Fixes) for the Markers I am finding on the code of my editor.

In summary, my quickfix is just replacing a piece of text where the marker is positioned... The quickfix works as expected for replacing the text, however, once the quickfix is applied the old marker is still there and some part of the text is still "underlined" with the warning of the old Marker.

You can check the code sample [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.37.1#XQAAAAJjBQAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw894kXbpo6KbyT6d2s9ZojPnuzKxfrOqkauMGuyn80RiA_W6BftmfFae8xvpkVeIw3aOBUMjdJAGWyoIhZHjezYznzT4coJSbYLWrzcCFfY410t8e_CK3vHwZFiqwf5zdmoqHcPC4Fp6xcX6e3JaV5p4hFvsYLLjZOPUNOZt9dXgstJVH_-OeEgaQCpjidBDR5j5bJYI6aulmV9XZUJP3Lf-umJRKZjNH8zTxg9KO6XHR9hGNqQHVZRG2JkenVgVS15Oil078Qt0HI6yCSuyfNPVBQXymDsP9uzCZfHTeRPZIeJuTHmtUiTHqBjB_lGar2q9qerieeIqdQL_b_kV8g7-RywF84hayWRhUfHxVmvs3rUYxVaSkfW0pvjPbQmTCBdLfLNgHp8Sw_fpugp_7I-MZAz8yMlk1aFNzux84voOeqkFI8OQcR866wC98br7kqi5MjCr8PHiw6QbW959WZas7rb_7mKmnKjB_Cy7djL6wshAZDLt6GTQWsaDJlKhf7giTNi6vMXzA_nneSQ6yr6cVdkUFb0eyvuUjsNgV9iOpiC0jTMjx2iNJCGcNbCBAJfwWFvF6i0WUqe7O-dQi2ER-WnBKTmDJ7I9k7gHCA4pl3KcjHAi6dt5ssyil51uA2s5HWgbYHElgf6nW5Bb2vZPR3XxmJbOx9shC9NaSlApiitdpHbJ1_RxQAAFjnOpq1ugz2XJkvAaVeZ35BXbbkjRfjTX51B3hrHNY-2a1nm0S-xaKugKMc3hcfU9_FW6r4xzdoGxWYZRT9ZJoXHHmUDECB_Zz445Kf-Q0_2USGT2dS2gWCHCPkFxWiBCTETe3rwfXdiS22LCkGFfZLp-W22n-uYCK_RWt6KQ2VJpZJA_Ds2LhZPyNCE4)

Do you know if there is a way to cleanup the Marker once the quickfix is applied? Or maybe an event-listener from the Monaco Editor to listen if a quickfix was applied?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`dispose` argument is a function that executes after quick fix is pressed. I changed [your code](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.37.1#XQAAAALOBQAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw9lSe67hIAsMdCQfS6GbiJd3W4-3JHN5UEaywZUfJSfYleLtkiNBsOQyA5HvQHTI0T3KaP9rU75PiOtk8v1Ene9VWjWJQgaH7sKiiINftlAbaVBEPPskuk872CV8rX34kQ5WyUDQhBwd4c4LgUce-P4bvlrpXR49lP27UWKv_IEh_i0nxszeJwyLcW8kJO1m6so6Bd13pZyWybHB5GK2ggpnQlWdl8TccyPHYD7Gpl6YdqU87ZBuR6nnUMEh56Sa29cSznjFBT1S77sK2QcT-Lk9JOJrVHpMmXoYZ29ZrnKBSIivoL7fuhZVEPR_KYWQhmw2lmEYcy32Cuw9osS86N5Ey1ZcMQt7Q_SZ47oWbMC_u5rXaut8vI4VoEO8OVGCG06ldJ5-BwQwggSDKTv7C4ze9lArj1wnuaftS8Z1-jPbEpuhr49eOc07MMKAnBlbW_kCpe7RMtBlpDOnVuCzrtubFv4eHPv_zL9CH7_F5xruNTfrToTsLccU8MXDseCVrS-Y8xklNG9jz0IupuO3I91jRUfvd8GlkdvWCjNjMzNDb3uoZbiihI69Nc6oS7WhrBv5SKFNVjwmpRJsIOeEkw1I1ncbpOLqRh3dikoLl4UsEayrnjaxIalb8ztx8ynmZxe2WhjYneu5zSN_FMMQuXanojpb0DePo39lFPrLpuImtX2p1er5-ieHUT-_fFTsA8Jdy8RloKtI2vEzmhpA67IscDv5F7hqr7Er39uvIpPqPJdC0rCu60ECDQ-xodAJ4j4fqTtH6fHi1OohrFXqzh7yNawY3TGIIjtEexesnhiUq4U0Ed053WWlX4tXCkQIx3KDspxo7aKQ6mDw2IMqsX21u0jbKVeGEZy1lDctFWj9E5BZvSVB1poZrg3Gh0pqPjX4VZCLUXf7vAe3qbyf2b5zkI73tCYHKuWUo-zZkPb7HQfmdFs3_8g3zQw) by extracting validate to global scope, and modified dispose like so:

```js
dispose: () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Delayed for 1 second.");
    validate(model);
}, 1000); }
```

I delayed it's execution because sometimes it doesn't work if there is no delay.

Second option (and probably more appropriate) is to call validate() when user changes text. Here is [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71742764/19933941) from which I took the following code sample:

```js
var handle = null;
ed.getModel().onDidChangeContent(() => {
    // debounce
    clearTimeout(handle);
    handle = setTimeout(() => validate(model), 500);
});
```